# How to connect to Remote desktop to copy files

Tags: vbscript

I am not able to copy files onto the remote machine. For manually copying files we log on to the remote desktop, go to that individual folder and then paste the files.
We connect to remote desktop by giving the information
Computer Name : targetserver.x.com
Username : xyz
password : xyz

I am able to copy files to my local machine
source folder = "\Sourceserver\Archive\folder1" 
target folder = "C:\Users\TEMPPAHIR\LearnVB\folder1"

but not able to connect to the server for copying files onto it, like not able to copy from 
source folder = "\Sourceserver\Archive\folder1" 
target folder = "\Targetserver\F\folder1"

I have tried the below code

```
Option Explicit
'Get environment variables
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objSystemEnv = objShell.Environment("SYSTEM")
Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

strEnvVarSinc = objSystemEnv("SINC_DATA")
strEnvVarPcData = objSystemEnv("PC_DATA")
strEnvVarArchive = objSystemEnv("ARCHIVE")
strComputerName =  objNetwork.ComputerName

Set objSystemEnv = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objNetwork = Nothing

'SINC_DATA_AREA
strSincPath = strEnvVarSinc & "\" & strArea
'PC_DATA_AREA
strPcDataPath = strEnvVarPcData & "\" & strArea
```

---

I am able to map the drive now finally on my local machine but getting an error while copying files on to it - error on (18,1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: permission denied. Is it because of some firewall or some other issue ? I am manually able to connect the same RD by giving in my username and password and then copy files onto the RD.
Please help !

```
    Option Explicit
Dim objNet, sFile, objFSO, Arg, var, strInfo, strComputer, strDomain, objSWbemLocator, objSWbemServices
Dim colSwbemObjectSet, strUser, strPassword, objNetwork, objProcess
Dim SourceFolder, TargetFolder, objWMIService, strMachine, strAltUsername, strAltPwd
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.NetWork") 

set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
objNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "T:" , "\\srv10219\F"
SourceFolder = "\\srv10218\Archive\BudgetPiecesStore\20151116_094107"
Wscript.echo "Source folder Name is : " & SourceFolder
TargetFolder = "\\srv10219\F\ICCdata\BudgetPiecesStore\"
Wscript.echo "Target folder Name is : " & TargetFolder

For Each sFile In objFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files 
objFSO.GetFile(sFile).Copy TargetFolder & "\" & objFSO.GetFileName(sFile),True 
WScript.Echo "Copying file : " & Chr(34) & objFSO.GetFileName(sFile) & Chr(34) & " to " & TargetFolder  
Set objNet = Nothing     
Next
```

Comment: Copying files via RDP doesn't perform too well. If possible you should [map a network drive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) and copy via SMB.

Comment: ok Thanks @AnsgarWiechers again.. But as I want to copy files to multiple RD based on the argument given to the script. I cannot map all those drives on the machine. Is there a way I can connect directly to that particular RD given the path and then copy files onto it ??

Comment: I fail to see why you can't map drives of multiple computers to your local machine. Of course you wouldn't map them all at once, but one after the other, and disconnect them before mapping the next one.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I am able to map drive on my machine now bt not able to copy files. please see my edited post above and help if possible. Thanks in advance for ur time !!

Comment: Your user account doesn't have permission to write to the remote share. You may need to provide explicit credentials when connecting the share.